# Asp.net web service returning xml instead of json to browser using http

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, web-services

I have a simple code that needs to return string in json using a browser.

```
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string FunctiGetJsononName(string str)
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        return ser.Serialize(str);
    }
```

The output I get is json inside of xml. I want the json without the XML.

I can't use void method as well.
Also, I am using framework 4.5.2 and empty template (I can't use anything else).

Answer (score 0):

```
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
[WebMethod]
public string  FunctiGetJsononName(string str){

    Context.Response.Clear();
    Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json"; 
........
}
```

Try this...might help u!!
it helped me ...

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I tried that and I still get the sme result.